# Bootstrap 4 Alpha Grid unable 2 tables on side by side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

As using Bootstrap 4, I'm aware the .col-xs are dropped, instead of .col, I have tested on bootstrap 3.5 which I'm using

```
    <div class="col-xs-4">
         Table left side goes here
     </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
         Table right side goes here
    </div>
```

And it works fine, as you can see it from [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/2A6WYSDrQb).

however, it's a bit different on Bootstrap 4 Alpha.

```
<div class="col-2">
    <h2 class="sub-header">Test Arear</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1">Test</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1">Test 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1">Test 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-10">
    <h2 class="sub-header">Ticket Number</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">1,002</td>
                    <td class="col-md-3">1,003</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1">1,004</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">1,005</td>
                    <td class="col-md-3">1,006</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1">1,002</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">1,021</td>
                    <td class="col-md-3">1,023</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see results from [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/yJseO7WxsD).

I want it on the side by side table but it's not side by side. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a row wrapper as bootstrap four is done on flex rather than floats so the columns now need to be wrapped to make them into columns

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2">
    <h2 class="sub-header">Test Arear</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">Test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">Test 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">Test 3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10">
    <h2 class="sub-header">Ticket Number</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">1,002</td>
            <td class="col-md-3">1,003</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">1,004</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">1,005</td>
            <td class="col-md-3">1,006</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">1,002</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">1,021</td>
            <td class="col-md-3">1,023</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/HhH4iRHDLX)

Comment: That's perfect, Seems I have overlooked the row wapper,  Thanks for your help. Need to go over on the bootstrap 4v Alpha document and reread the Flex grid system again.